# Как получить статус код webdriver-manager/selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь через selenium 4.x и другие ванильные штуки достучаться до сайта. Соединение появляется, но, когда я хочу получить статус-код - оно падает.

Код следующий (Некоторые моменты упростил)

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class Driver(): 
    """В зависимости от выбранного браузера настраивает драйвера"""
    def __init__(self, checkBrowser):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    
    def getDriver(self): 
        return self.driver

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    dr = Driver('Google').getDriver()
    dr.get('https://www.flashscorekz.com/basketball/usa/nba/results/')
    print(dir(dr.requests))
```

Раньше пользовался таким методом

```
driver.requests
```

Через него мог уже найти статусы соединения. Теперь падает ошибка

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'requests'
```

Если смотреть все методы и атрибуты `driver` через `dir`, то там и правда нет такого атрибута. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить стату-код? Раньше ведь это работало. Что теперь использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое - я просто опечатался при импорте

Изначально `seleinum` не имеет такого метода, поэтому есть сахар - `selenium-wire`

Я в новом модуле импортировал `selenium`, а должен был `seleniumwire`